# Unable to connect to my VM instance using neither from Chrome RDP for Google Cloud Platform nor from my computer RDC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an urgent project. I chose the free trial of Google Cloud Platform to create a VM instance that I can configure and put my server in. However it appears that I can't RDP to the VM instance of Windows server 2012 R2. Also, I can't even ping the instance with the external IP. I tried from the Chrome RDP for Google Platform it doesn't work. I tried also the Remote Desktop Connection from my computer still doesn't work. Always showing the same error as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AXO2.png). By the way the port 3389 in the firewall is already allowed and given the highest priority of 65535. I don't know what is the problem.

Note: I can't ping the external IP. There must be something that I am missing somewhere could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

65535 is actually the [lowest priority](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#priority_order_for_firewall_rules).

- The default VPC network allows traffic on 3389 with a rule with a priority of 1000; did you delete that rule?
- Did you specify a different VPC network from the default for the VM's network? If so, you'll need to permit traffic on that VPC network as well (the [default rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) only apply to the default network).
- Did the machine finish booting before you attempted to connect to it?
- Did you [set a password for it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances) before attempting to connect?

Post a screenshot of your firewall rules if nothing in this answer resolves the issue.